# Преобразование HTML в картинку

Tags: c#, .net

Подскажите бесплатную библиотеку для рендеринга HTML.
На данный момент в проекте используется СEF Offscreen. В браузер загружается HTML сниппет и делается скриншот. Однако сам CEF занимает достаточно много места на диске и жрёт память. Возможно есть альтернативы? Не хочется тащить за собой столько библиотек ради отрисовки небольшой статической странички (содержит CSS).

Comment: Преобразовать HTML в картинку — это основная задача браузера. Учитывая сложность современного HTML, браузер не может быть легковесным. Если я правильно понял, то CEF — это браузер Хромиум. Возможные варианты: или использовать системный браузер или заранее пререндеренную картинку.

Comment: _"Если я правильно понял, то CEF - это браузер Хромиум"_ - Да. _"заранее пререндеренную картинку."_ - Не подходит, разметка меняется перед загрузкой в браузер. _"использовать системный браузер"_ - Каким образом?

Comment: Хотите легковесность, берите и парсите этот HTML в банальные свойства и классы, а уже потом, как спарсите, делайте с этими данными все, что хотите, хоть формируйте интерфейс на их основе и фоткайте его. Ну а если хотите костыль с браузером, то в любом фреймворке есть свой браузер, старый, ужасный, но есть, например `WebBrowser`. Если его мало, то берите современное, например `WebView2`. Но опять же, это как по мне костыль...

Comment: _"Но опять же, это как по мне костыль"_ - Потому что WebView2 внутри использует MS Edge? У меня `DrawToBitmap` просто одноцветную картинку возвращает. Это нормально? [Рабочее решение?](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/529#issuecomment-1021262814)

Comment: `WebBrowser` по мне так ужасен. Даже текст нечёткий получается в простом HTML сниппете. Не стал пробовать свой код где много CSS. Всё таки считаете лучше оставить CEF? Функциональность не первостепенная, но нужная, хоть CEF и занимает наверное процентов 90 веса всего проекта.

Comment: "Костыль" - я говорю не про браузер (`WebView2` это отличная вещь), а про то, что вы пытаетесь взять UI (HTML) и его отобразить (сделать скрин), когда как по-хорошему, надо парсить данные из HTML в обычный набор классов, а затем уже выводить в нужном виде. Поэтому думайте сами, хорее вообще решение, брать полноценный браузер, лишь для того, чтоб сделать скрин... Я изначально сказал, что это костыль) "отндцветную картинку" - без понятия, не занимался скринами браузеров.

Comment: Вообще, тут все зависит от той страницы, что вы пытаетесь вывести. Если это просто табличка - как и сказал выше, просто спарсите данные из HTML, сделайте табличку в своем приложении встроенными методами, и ее скринти. Если это полноценный сайт - то смысл его скринить я не пойму... Ради чего? Замена интерфейса? Если да, то идите сразу в Electron, который из веб приложений делает десктоп, а другие варианты, ну... Бессмысленны. Если как некий макет для формирования данных, то можно [преобразовать](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aa972129(v=vs.100)) в XAML например.

Comment: _"а про то, что вы пытаетесь взять UI (HTML) и его отобразить (сделать скрин), когда как по-хорошему, надо парсить данные из HTML в обычный набор классов, а затем уже выводить в нужном виде."_ - Это нужно не для представления в UI. Выполняется сбор данных с сайта и требуется прикрепить развертку, которая рисуется векторной графикой на сайте.

Comment: То есть есть некоторые области, задаваемые точками, которые нужно раскрасить в определённые цвета. Эти точки загружаются в HTML элемент, тот загружается в браузер и делается скриншот.